# Facebook javascript SDK share image issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, social-networking, sharing

I want to make custom button for an image sharing via Facebook.

I've added JS SDK script at first:

`<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>`

Then I've added `FB.ui` function on button click:

```
$('.fb.btn').click(function() {
   // Open FB share popup
   FB.ui({
      method: 'share_open_graph',
      action_type: 'og.shares',
      action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: {
               'og:url': window.location.href,
               'og:title': 'My Title',
               'og:description': 'Some description here',
               'og:image': 'img url'
            }
      })
   },
   function (response) {
      // Action after response
   });
});
```

So, I want to specify link for the main page of my website as `og:url`.

Also I want to specify picture for sharing which is in `images` folder.

But `FB.ui` function ignores all `og` parameters except `og:url`. It takes website URL and pulls all parameters from the URL but not from specified params in `FB.ui` function. It doesn't show specified image inside shared link, it just gets any image from the main link (`og:url`). The same for title.

Why it takes all stuff from one page anyway despite that fact that I can specify these params separately?

I want to pass `www.example.com` as `og:url`, `Hello World` as `og:title` and `www.example.com/images/hello.jpg` as `og:image`.

How to use `FB.ui` function and pass exact the same params as I specified regardless to `og:url` page?

Comment: You can't. You have to put the og-tags on the page that you are sharing

Comment: Unfortunately og-tags not working on the static page too

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: For what should I set all of these parameters (og:title, og:description, og:image) then?

Comment: You put those tags on the page that you share. You can set them to anything you want.

Comment: But `FB.ui` requires these parameters too regardless to the page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198321/discussion-between-mr-boris-and-wizkid).

Comment: No it doesn't. How to use FB.ui to share is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I can't figure out what to put for those parameters....

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt, I figure out that the only way to make it work is to place static page with proper `og:` meta tags and then give links for sharing right to this page. Look my solution in next answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it works for me only if I put static page with proper `og:` tags on my domain and then give a link for sharing right for this special page.

Make request for sharing link via Facebook example:

```
function share_fb(url) {
   window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(url),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=1200,height=630', '_blank');
}

var shareLinkFB = 'www.example.com/page_for_fb_sharing.html';

share_fb(shareLinkFB);
```

Example page for sharing link ( **[www.example.com/page_for_fb_sharing.html](http://www.example.com/page_for_fb_sharing.html)** ) on your server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   
   <meta property="og:title" content="My website title" />
   <meta property="og:description" content="Some description" />
   <meta property="og:caption" content="Also caption" />
   <meta property="og:image" content="www.example.com/images/sharing_image.png">
   <meta property="og:url" content="www.example.com/page_for_fb_sharing.html">

   <title>Playstation</title>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- just empty body -->
</body>
</html>
```

And now Facebook must show title and image properly in sharing message when you make request within `share_fb` function.

Also this page might be dynamic ( i.e. **[www.example.com/page_for_fb_sharing/{id}](http://www.example.com/page_for_fb_sharing/%7Bid%7D)** ) if you configure route on the backend but the main thing is to have identical URLs for `og:url` meta tag and for sharing link itself respectively otherwise Facebook will not find your sharing page and sharing link will be broken.

So that using this approach you can prepare a bunch of static pages and give different sharing links according to them or make dynamic page. Also you can put JS script in the body of this sharing page and make auto redirect to another page to have one sharing page especially for FB share rendering but dynamic for further redirect hit.

`<script>window.location.replace('www.example.com/quiz_result.html?result={value}');</script>`

---

There is no need to use FB SDK at all in this case.

Remove `<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>`